# Running Beautiful Soup in AWS Lambda without PhantomJS

Tags: python, python-2.7, selenium, beautifulsoup, aws-lambda

Although there is a 5 min limit, I am looking to run some small scrape projects using AWS Lambda with Beautiful Soup.

Previously I have always done this using EC2 alongside PhantomJS. Now that PhantomJS is deprecated and doesn't work on a Python lambda container anyway. I am looking for an alternative solution perhaps using Chrome or Firefox. Plus it leaves a huge waste of resources at EC2 between scrapes. So looking at Lambda with a bit of automation too.

Is it just a case of adding Firefox or Chrome Python modules (to replace PhantomJS as browser) or do the Chrome binaries need building?

https://pypi.org/project/chromedriver_installer/

Comment: Can you just use urllib or headless Selenium on Chrome to fetch your html pages, then parse them with BeautifulSoup? Here's an example on OSX: https://gist.github.com/duhaime/ab62295f6aedb9c2300471afd5ae7ef9

Comment: It's the building/getting Chrome working that I am struggling with.

Comment: Try using puppeteer on Lambda, which this project has made a bit easier: https://github.com/sean-hill/aws-puppeteer-lambda

Comment: Does puppeteer pair OK with selenium and Beautiful Soup?